# Calculate rainfall with lists in python

Tags: python, list, math

I have to write a program that asks the user to enter in the total rainfall for each month of the year.

So far my code takes the rainfall for each month of the year and gives the total, and the average.

All I can't figure out is how do I give each index a month so that I can have it give the month with the lowest rainfall and the month with the highest rainfall Eg. May had the most rainfall this year.

I want to keep everything how I have it just add the following above.

Thanks.

```
Number_of_months = 12
NumberList = []
total = 0

for i in range(Number_of_months):
    rainfall = eval(input("enter in the rainfall for each month(starting with January - December):"))
    NumberList.append(rainfall)
    total += rainfall

average = total / Number_of_months

print(NumberList)
print("The total rainfall of the year is:",total)
print("The average is", average)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a list with the names of the months that you want.

```
months = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', ... fill in the rest]
```

Find the index of the min / max rainfall values in `NumberList`

```
max_index = NumberList.index(max(NumberList))
min_index = NumberList.index(min(NumberList))
```

Get the names of the months using the index values you found in the previous step:

```
max_month = months[max_index]
min_month = months[min_index]
```